# Passing data from form to fieldset

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've got custom fieldset class like `CustomerFieldset`. I add it to the form like this:

```
$someData = $this->getSomeData();

$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'customfieldset',
    'type' => CustomFieldset::class,
));
```

How to pass `$someData` to this fieldset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the fieldset elements and set a value simply use

```
$form->get('customfieldset')->get('elementName')->setvalue('value');
```

If you want to pass other data then in your fielset create a property to hold it and create a setter.

```
private $propertyName;

public function setProperty($value)
(
    $this->propertyName = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

and call it from your form

```
$form->get('customfieldset')->setProperty($value);
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.